# How to get contents of HTML Script tag

Tags: python, pandas, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape the geo data from a URL for my scraping practice. But I'm having trouble while handling contents of script tag.

Following is the contents of script tag :

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
     "address": {
            "@type": "PostalAddress",
            "streetAddress": "5080 Riverside Drive",
            "addressLocality": "Macon",
            "addressRegion": "GA",
            "postalCode": "31210-1100",
            "addressCountry": "US"
        },
        "telephone": "478-471-0171",
        "geo": {
            "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
            "latitude": "32.9252435",
            "longitude": "-83.7145993"
        }
    }
    </script>
```

I want to add contents of script tag (city, state, lat, long and phone no.) to my result.

Following is my code(incomplete) :

```
def parse(self,response)
    items = MyItem()
    tree = Selector(response)

    items['city'] = tree.xpath('//script/text()').extract()[0]
    items['state'] = tree.xpath('//script/text()').extract()[0]
    items['latitude'] = tree.xpath('//script/text()').extract()[0]
    items['longitude'] = tree.xpath('//script/text()').extract()[0]
    items['telephone'] = tree.xpath('//script/text()').extract()[0]
    print(items)
    yield items
```

Can I get any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: Tag names, such as python or scrapy, are not needed in titles. That's what we have tags for.

Comment: Should I collect the contents of script tag and then convert it into a dictionary using ast.literal_eval() or is there any other efficient solution for this?

Comment: I was discussing the format of your question, not the content itself. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you're trying to do with the repeated xpath queries `//item/title/text()`. Note that xpath is useful for extracting HTML content. The content of the `<script>` tag in your question is not HTML, so it's not possible to query that with xpath.

In a first step you can get the content of the `<script>` tag:

```
content = tree.xpath('//script/text()').extract()[0]
```

And then you can use the `json` package to load the json content into a Python dictionary:

```
d = json.loads(content)
```

Also note that the JSON in the `<script>` in your example is not valid,
it's missing a closing brace.
The above method only works with valid content.

Comment: I was trying with xpath then I came to know that it is only for extracting html content. That's why I've written incomplete code. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: what if there are more than one script tag.. Does tree.xpath('//script/text()').extract()[n] will work for the nth script tag?

Comment: @AvinashClinton exactly