# How to write scraped response from multiple pages into a single file/dataframe

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

This question is an extension of [How to get contents of HTML Script tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49327937/how-to-get-contents-of-html-script-tag/49328401?noredirect=1#comment85658845_49328401)

I'm scraping geo location using custom_parse method for each of the URL from collection of URls scrapped in the parse method.

```
def parse(self, response)
    ...
    ... 
    for i in range(len(url)):
        yield Request(url[i], callback=self.custom_parse)
        time.sleep(3)

def custom_parse(self, response):
    items = MyItem()
    tree = Selector(response)

    script = tree.xpath('//script/text()').extract()[3]
    info = json.loads(script)
    items['address'] = info['address']['streetAddress']
    items['city'] = info['address']['addressLocality']
    items['state'] = info['address']['addressRegion']
    items['latitude'] = info['geo']['latitude']
    items['longitude'] = info['geo']['longitude']
    items['phone_number'] = info['telephone']
    df = pd.DataFrame([item],columns=item.keys())
    yield items
```

custom_parse will execute and yield items or return df(if i return df instead of yielding items) for each of the URL.

But how can I combine this into a single dataframe(where each row corresponds to the geo info of respective URL).

Similarly if dataframe is not my option, how can i write response yielded from multiple URLs into a single file.

Comment: So `custom_parse` can return a `DataFrame` with each row giving the geo information for a single URL and you simply want to combine multiple URLs into a single DataFrame at the end?

Comment: Yes. Basically I want to combine the result(for each url) into one dataframe at the end and want to save that dataframe into a file.

Comment: So I'm not familiar with yield, but it sounds like what you can do is first create an empty list `df_list = []` and then inside of that for loop have `custom_parse` return a `df` and use `df_list.append(custom_parse(*args))`. This will create a list of DataFrames, one for each run of the loop. After the loop you can just use pandas `pandas.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)` to join that list into a single DataFrame. But if you need to use yield, I'm not too sure.